# How to build Eclipse JDT Core from source code via Git?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, eclipse-jdt

I want to build Eclipse JDT Core from source code via Git.  Naïvely, I cloned `git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git` and tried to run `mvn validate` (the most basic of Maven phases) from the Git `master` branch but this failed with errors below.

I am a Debian Linux user with Maven 3.0.5 and JDK 1.7 installed.

I am interested to hack on class [ASTParser](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTParser.html), which can parse Java code.  I realise building Eclipse projects is hard, but I cannot find the definitive "recipe" page anywhere on the Net for building this project.

In my Eclipse Juno installation (updated to latest), this is my JDT Core JAR file: `org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.8.3.v20130121-145325.jar`.  I tried to build on this tag (`v20130121-145325`), but I get a similar error.

Log from `mvn validate` on Git branch `master`:

```
kca@cwb:~/saveme/git/eclipse.jdt.core$ mvn validate
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Computing target platform for MavenProject: org.eclipse.jdt:org.eclipse.jdt.annotation:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT @ /home/kca/saveme/git/eclipse.jdt.core/org.eclipse.jdt.annotation/pom.xml
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20130517111416/repository
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20130517111416/repository
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/rt/ecf/int7/site.p2
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/rt/ecf/int7/site.p2
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-bundles-8.x/8.1.10.v20130312
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-bundles-8.x/8.1.10.v20130312
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/updates/2.9/base/R201305280742
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/updates/2.9/base/R201305280742
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/license
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/license
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/egit/staging/v3.0.0.201305080800-m7
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/egit/staging/v3.0.0.201305080800-m7
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/aspectj/update/e42
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/aspectj/update/e42
[INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: org.eclipse.jdt:org.eclipse.jdt.annotation:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT @ /home/kca/saveme/git/eclipse.jdt.core/org.eclipse.jdt.annotation/pom.xml
[INFO] Resolving class path of MavenProject: org.eclipse.jdt:org.eclipse.jdt.annotation:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT @ /home/kca/saveme/git/eclipse.jdt.core/org.eclipse.jdt.annotation/pom.xml
[INFO] Computing target platform for MavenProject: org.eclipse.jdt:org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool:1.0.200-SNAPSHOT @ /home/kca/saveme/git/eclipse.jdt.core/org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool/pom.xml
[INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: org.eclipse.jdt:org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool:1.0.200-SNAPSHOT @ /home/kca/saveme/git/eclipse.jdt.core/org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool/pom.xml
[INFO] Cannot complete the request.  Generating details.
[INFO] Cannot complete the request.  Generating details.
[INFO] {osgi.ws=gtk, osgi.os=linux, osgi.arch=x86, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true}
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool 1.0.200.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.0.qualifier requires 'bundle org.eclipse.text [3.1.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool 1.0.200.qualifier depends on: bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core [3.3.0,4.0.0)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.": ["Unable to satisfy dependency from org.apache.ant 1.8.2.v201303080311 to bundle org.eclipse.osgi 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.apache.ant 1.8.3.v201303080312 to bundle org.eclipse.osgi 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.apache.ant 1.8.4.v201303080030 to bundle org.eclipse.osgi 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.0.qualifier to bundle org.eclipse.text [3.1.0,4.0.0).", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.0.qualifier to bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.3.0,4.0.0).", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.0.qualifier to bundle org.eclipse.core.filesystem [1.0.0,2.0.0).", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.0.qualifier to bundle org.eclipse.core.resources [3.3.0,4.0.0).", "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable."] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.": ["Unable to satisfy dependency from org.apache.ant 1.8.2.v201303080311 to bundle org.eclipse.osgi 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.apache.ant 1.8.3.v201303080312 to bundle org.eclipse.osgi 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.apache.ant 1.8.4.v201303080030 to bundle org.eclipse.osgi 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.0.qualifier to bundle org.eclipse.text [3.1.0,4.0.0).", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.0.qualifier to bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.3.0,4.0.0).", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.0.qualifier to bundle org.eclipse.core.filesystem [1.0.0,2.0.0).", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.0.qualifier to bundle org.eclipse.core.resources [3.3.0,4.0.0).", "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable."]
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:168)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.": ["Unable to satisfy dependency from org.apache.ant 1.8.2.v201303080311 to bundle org.eclipse.osgi 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.apache.ant 1.8.3.v201303080312 to bundle org.eclipse.osgi 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.apache.ant 1.8.4.v201303080030 to bundle org.eclipse.osgi 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.0.qualifier to bundle org.eclipse.text [3.1.0,4.0.0).", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.0.qualifier to bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.3.0,4.0.0).", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.0.qualifier to bundle org.eclipse.core.filesystem [1.0.0,2.0.0).", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.0.qualifier to bundle org.eclipse.core.resources [3.3.0,4.0.0).", "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable."]
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.AbstractResolutionStrategy.newResolutionException(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:98)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.ProjectorResolutionStrategy.resolve(ProjectorResolutionStrategy.java:88)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.AbstractResolutionStrategy.resolve(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.doResolvePlatform(P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:374)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.resolveDependencies(P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:350)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:82)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:274)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        ... 11 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/InternalErrorException
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run

`mvn -P build-individual-bundles package` from eclipse.jdt.core folder.