# Build Failure for Eclipse-JDT Core with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, compiler-errors, eclipse-jdt

I use **[org.eclipse.jdt.core](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.core)** as a dependency in my code. I want to perform a small modification (make the constructor public) to the abstract class [ASTNode](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.core/blob/master/org.eclipse.jdt.core/dom/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTNode.java) in **org.eclipse.jdt.core**. After performing the modification I want to build it and use the compiled **jar** file in my project as a dependency **jar**.

Hence I want to build Eclipse JDT Core from source code via Git. Naïvely, I cloned
`git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git` and executed `mvn -P build-individual-bundles package` as suggested in [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943750/how-to-build-eclipse-jdt-core-from-source-code-via-git).

I get the error below after a few minutes. Any ideas? TIA!

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] Internal error: org.eclipse.tycho.core.ee.UnknownEnvironmentException: Unknown OSGi execution environment: 'JavaSE-13' -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: org.eclipse.tycho.core.ee.UnknownEnvironmentException: Unknown OSGi execution environment: 'JavaSE-13'
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.tycho.core.ee.UnknownEnvironmentException: Unknown OSGi execution environment: 'JavaSE-13'
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.ee.ExecutionEnvironmentUtils.getExecutionEnvironment (ExecutionEnvironmentUtils.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.OsgiBundleProject.applyBestOfCurrentOrConfiguredProfile (OsgiBundleProject.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.OsgiBundleProject.readExecutionEnvironmentConfiguration (OsgiBundleProject.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.setupProject (DefaultTychoResolver.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead (TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/InternalErrorException
```

Comment: Does your modification include switching to Java 13? Which Tycho version do you use?

Comment: I use Tycho 2.0.0.

Comment: Tycho 2.0.0 has not yet been released. The error message tells something about `'JavaSE-13'`, but in JDT and in the platform `JavaSE-13` is not used et all (currently it is `JavaSE-1.8` and future release might use `JavaSE-11`). That's why I asked you if you'd changed that (it seems very likely that the issue is caused by your modifications). I recommend to try to build it without the modifications, to narrow down the issue.